# Repositories and Roots of aggregates

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories

I'm reading a book by Eric Evans DDD.
And I found a contradiction.

**Chapter books about aggregates:**

> Choose one ENTITY to be the root of each AGGREGATE, and control all
>   access to the objects inside the boundary through the root.

**Chapter books about repositories:**

> A subset of persistent objects must be globally accessible through a
>   search based on object attributes. Such access is needed for the roots
>   of AGGREGATES that are not convenient to reach by traversal. They are
>   usually ENTITIES, sometimes VALUE OBJECTS with complex internal
>   structure, and sometimes enumerated VALUES. Providing access to other
>   objects muddies important distinctions.
>
> Provide REPOSITORIES only for AGGREGATE roots that actually need
>   direct access.

**It can be concluded that the root of the aggregate can be:**

- entity
- value object
- enumerated values

Correctly I understood everything?

**Or may be right:**

Provide REPOSITORIES only for

- aggregate roots
- value objects
- enumerated values
  ?

And what is enumerated values(which needs its own repository!)?

Comment: the root of an aggregate is always an entity. also, you only provide repositories for aggregate roots. value objects and enums do not have a life cycle and need to be located by a global unique identity.

Comment: But for global access value objects and enums require their own repositories. Isn't it?

Comment: value objects are identified by their attributes not a global id. depending upon the bounded context a value object may be an aggregate in another BC. also, vaughn vernon calls enums/lookup data Standard Types and can simply be loaded from the data source.

Answer (score 0):

Per @Marco's comment above, the root of an aggregate can only be an entity (i.e. something with an ID property).  An example of this would be an `Order` object.  No matter how many attributes you change on an `Order` its quality is determined by its `Id` property and nothing else.

A [value object](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html) (often implemented as a `struct` in many languages) does not have an ID.  A common example of this would be a `Money` value object with a `Dollars` property and `Cents` property.  Because it has no ID, the concept of querying it by ID does not apply, and thus the concept of a repository does not apply.  An aggregate could have a value object as a property, though (e.g. the `Total` property on an `Order` aggregate).

An [enumerated type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enumerated_type) is just a list of name/value pairs.  It uses the `enum` keyword in several languages.  Again, there's no ID for the enum nor any of its members, so the concept of a repository does not apply.  The concept of an enum is useful in DDD because it helps express the domain model better than, say, magic numbers e.g. `order.Status = OrderStatus.Submitted` vs `order.Status = 1`.